# Object reference not set to an object error while moving an object to feature list

Tags: 2013, feature

I have created a feature in which I want to put the list instance to be created when the feature is activated.

I created new feature from visual studio and trying to add the list instance file to the "Items in the feature" list. But when I press the move button after selecting the object I am getting the above mentioned error.

What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Close the open Feature window, open it again and try adding the object again.

That is the solution I have used in the same situation (VS 2012), but I'm still unsure of why this happens!